# How to draw outline of a point in OpenGL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, render, point

By now points can be drawn with the following code:

```
    // SETUP FOR VERTICES
GLfloat points[graph->vertexCount * 6];
for (int i = 0 ; i < graph->vertexCount; i++) 
{
    points[i*6] = (graph->vertices[i].x / (backingWidth/2) ) - 1;
    points[i*6+1] = -(graph->vertices[i].y / (backingHeight/2) ) + 1;

    points[i*6+2] = 1.0;
    points[i*6+3] = 0.0;
    points[i*6+4] = 0.0;
    points[i*6+5] = 1.0;
}

glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glPointSize(DOT_SIZE*scale); 
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 24, points);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 24, &points[2]);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, graph->vertexCount);
```

The points are rendered with red color, and I want to add a white outline outside the points. How can I draw outline of the point?

**Question for better displaying**

Follow @BDL 's instruction adding bigger points under the red points as outline, they look good.

```
outlinePoints[i*6] = (graph->vertices[i].x / (backingWidth/2) ) - 1;
outlinePoints[i*6+1] = -(graph->vertices[i].y / (backingHeight/2) ) + 1;
outlinePoints[i*6+2] = 0.9;
outlinePoints[i*6+3] = 0.9;
outlinePoints[i*6+4] = 0.9;
outlinePoints[i*6+5] = 1.0;
```

But when one point overlaps another point, it's outline is covered by the red point, since the outline points are rendered before all the red points.

[image]

I think the right solution is to render one outline point and red point one by one. How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean with outline ... a convex hull of the points?

Comment: If you mean a outline for each single point, then render a white, slightly larger point first and then the red point.

Comment: @jdleung Does the answere from BDL worked for you?

Comment: @BDL Thanks, it's a good idea. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Yes, it works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render outlines for each point separately, then you can simply render a slightly larger white point first and then render the red point over it. With depth-testing enabled, you might have to adjust the polygon offset when rendering the red point to prevent them from getting hidden behind the white ones.

Comment: I got a new question for better displaying, please take a look at the edited old question. Thx.

Comment: @jdleung You should ask a new question for that and reference this question. You should also make it clearer which result you expect. The outline of which point should be displayed completely, the one from the left point or from the right point. How do you determine which point should be in front?

Comment: here is the  [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253903/better-overlapping-points-in-opengl)