# Better overlapping points in OpenGL

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, render, point

I'm using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209783/how-to-draw-outline-of-a-point-in-opengl/50248137?noredirect=1#comment87521448_50248137) to simulate the outline of a point.

```
GLfloat points[graph->vertexCount * 6];
GLfloat outlinePoints[graph->vertexCount * 6];

for (int i = 0 ; i < graph->vertexCount; i++) 
{
    outlinePoints[i*6] = (graph->vertices[i].x / (backingWidth/2) ) - 1;
    outlinePoints[i*6+1] = -(graph->vertices[i].y / (backingHeight/2) ) + 1;
    outlinePoints[i*6+2] = 0.9;
    outlinePoints[i*6+3] = 0.9;
    outlinePoints[i*6+4] = 0.9;
    outlinePoints[i*6+5] = 1.0;

    points[i*6] = (graph->vertices[i].x / (backingWidth/2) ) - 1;
    points[i*6+1] = -(graph->vertices[i].y / (backingHeight/2) ) + 1;
    points[i*6+2] = 1.0;
    points[i*6+3] = 0.0;
    points[i*6+4] = 0.0;
    points[i*6+5] = 1.0;
}

// for outline points
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glPointSize(DOT_SIZE*scale*1.2); 
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 24, outlinePoints); 
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 24, &outlinePoints[2]);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, graph->vertexCount);

// for red points
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glPointSize(DOT_SIZE*scale); 
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 24, points);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 24, &points[2]);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, graph->vertexCount);
```

The points display as I wish when there is no overlapping.

[image]

But when one point overlaps another point, the white outline is covered by the red point.
[image]

I think the reason is that the outline points are all put into an array and rendered before all the red points. The rendering order should be "(white point, red point), (white point, red point)...", something like white point and red point are grouped.

It should be like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

------------  **Temporary solution edited on 12th**  ------------

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i < graph->vertexCount; i++)
{
    GLfloat points[6];
    GLfloat outlinePoints[6];

    outlinePoints[0] = (graph->vertices[i].x / (backingWidth/2) ) - 1;
    outlinePoints[1] = -(graph->vertices[i].y / (backingHeight/2) ) + 1;
    outlinePoints[2] = 0.9;
    outlinePoints[3] = 0.9;
    outlinePoints[4] = 0.9;
    outlinePoints[5] = 1.0;

    glPointSize(DOT_SIZE*scale*1.3); 
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 24, outlinePoints);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 24, &outlinePoints[2]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

    // red points
    points[0] = (graph->vertices[i].x / (backingWidth/2) ) - 1;
    points[1] = -(graph->vertices[i].y / (backingHeight/2) ) + 1;
    points[2] = 1.0;
    points[3] = 0.0;
    points[4] = 0.0;
    points[5] = 1.0;

    glPointSize(DOT_SIZE*scale);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 24, points);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 24, &points[2]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
}
```

The above code can draw points as I expect, but the following code have to run twice when each point is drawing, just don't know how much it will impact the rendering speed if points increase?

```
    glPointSize(DOT_SIZE*scale);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 24, points);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 24, &points[2]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
```

Comment: It is still unclear which point should be in front. The one that has the higher index in the array? There are ways to achieve what you want by utilizing the depth buffer (e.g. store a z-component that makes sure that further away points will not overdraws closer ones)

Comment: @BDL Let's try to regard the outline point and red point as one point (it was like this, we cannot make one with outline, then we make two), we call it completed point. Then, no matter how many completed points and which is in the front.

Comment: @Rabbid76 It's another good choice if a shader can simulate an outline, how to do that? and how to render points one by one? Z-coordinate is also a good choice, I tried to add glOrthof, not work.

Comment: If you want to render an outline computationally, render a single point, and compute distance of the fragment from the point center (gl_FragCoord). Change shader color based on the computed radius.

Comment: @solidpixel, I tried to find way to draw outline and shader, but since a newbie of OpenGL, have no idea. I'm considering a maybe simple way that is to set size array so as to draw different size of points. I'v search for a lot, someone made it work but I didn't :-(

Comment: If find the way to draw different size of points in one time rendering, red point data and outline point data can be put together, then be drawn in order: outline point -> red point -> outline point -> red point....

Comment: @BDL I added a temporary solution in the post, just don't know how much it will impact the rendering speed. Any suggestion?